# Passing props while using React Native Testing and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-testing-library

Hey I am trying to implement the react-native-testing-library for a project which is also using TypeScript. My question involves the best way to pass props to my tests.

For example if my src/example.tsx is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

export interface Props {
    text: string;
    func: () => void;
}

export const Example: React.FC<Props> = ({ text, func }: Props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Button onPress={func} title={text} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

And my src/**test**/example.test.tsx is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { Example, Props } from '../example';

describe('example', () => {
    const { getAllBy } = render(<Example {...Props} />); <---- *Error
}
```

I obviously get the error:

```
'Props' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

What is the best way to do this. Do I need to manually create a mock props object to feed into each of my components or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "Do I need to manually create a mock props object to feed into each of my components" Yup

Comment: https://medium.com/@vittorioguerriero/typescript-mock-for-real-b15147fddd92